# Reason for destructuring props in react - apart from syntactic sugar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this concept isn't unique to react, but i couldn't find another reason to do this apart from shorter and more readable code.

Comment: You won't override your props object by accident if you destructure it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the principle reason: conciseness, clarity, readability. That's more than reason enough to have it.

But there are other reasons:

- If you destructure on receipt, you can assign to the destructured parameters without fear of changing the object that was passed in.
- By saying declaratively to the JavaScript engine which properties you're using from the object passed in, it may make it possible or easier for the engine to optimize. For instance, maybe it can just pass those properties rather than the object reference itself; if the target function creates closures and the calling code drops its reference to the object, that may make it possible for the object to be reclaimed. Thorough code analysis might make that possible without destructuring, but destructuring makes it easier (i.e., faster for the engine to do, which may make the difference between doing it and not doing it).

Answer (score -2):

another way to pass props is with a direct object:

```
function UserInfo({username}){
      return (
        <div className="UserInfo">
          <div className="UserInfo-name">
            {username}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: That's not at all what the question is asking about.